# Join string php if some var is true

Tags: php, string

lets say we have code

```
$somestring = "amazing text" . $something . "lol";
```

Is it possible somehow to add $something part only when some

```
$myvar == true
```

but without doing:

```
if ($myvar) 
   $somestring = "amazing text" . $something . "lol";
else
   $somestring = "amazing text" . "lol";
```

something inline like

```
$somestring = "amazing text" . if($myvar) $something . "lol";
```

It would be pretty nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$somestring = "amazing text".($myvar ? $something : "")."lol";
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Answer (score 1):

```
$somestring = "amazing text" . ($myvar?$something:'') . "lol";
```